# JavaScript: Decode base64 into binary data

Tags: javascript, binary, base64

I'm trying to create a image from a video by using a canvas and then sending the image to an API.

This is my code (large parts are omitted for brevity)

```
      var image = new Image();
        image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      var newFile = new File([atob(image.src)], lorem.png, {
         type: "image/png",
          lastModified: Date.now()
         })
```

image.src is a long string that seems to be in the format base64 data:image/png;base64

[Link to the data ][1]:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d357e780fa60b2c47490a9f795e34acf

When I try to decode the data into binary with the function *atob*, I get the following error:

> Error: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded
>   is not correctly encoded.

It's not clear to me which part of the base64 data are not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cut of the head of the data url. When you put the image into image.src its content is like `data:image/png;base64,BASE64ENCODEDSTUFF`.
Obsviously `data:image/png;base64`, is not base64 so decoding it with atob will fail.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work first, because a data-uri consists of a header then followed by the Base-64 data - atob() can only deal with the Base-64 part. This means you need to cut off the header ("data:image/png;base64,").

But going via Data-URI is slow and wastes more memory than needed. Use a blob directly - this is how:

```
var img = new Image();

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  var newFile = new File([blob], "lorem.png", {type: "image/png"});
  img.src = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my go to solution to convert an Base64 type image to binary file. This can handle other types of files also.

```
export const dataType64toFile = (dataurl, filename = "NewFile") => {
  //Convert base64 to file
  let arr = dataurl.split(","),
    mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
    bstr = atob(arr[1]),
    n = bstr.length,
    u8arr = new Uint8Array(n)
  while (n--) {
    u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n)
  }
  let newFile = new File([u8arr], filename, {
    type: mime,
  })
  return newFile
}
```